# transform: translateX is affecting transform: translateY

Tags: html, css, transform, translate

I'm trying to animate a burger menu. When I try to change the X coordinate in `.burger-icon:before` - `transform: translateX(20px)` - it changes the Y as well. Thanks!

Here is HTML:

```
<button class="menu-button" type="button" data-toggle="-menu" id="burger-button">
    <span class="burger-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.menu-button.is-active .burger-icon {
    transform: translateY(2px) rotate(135deg);
}
.menu-button.is-active .burger-icon:before {
    transform: translateX(20px) translateY(10px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu-button.is-active .burger-icon:after {
    transform: translateY(-19px) rotate(33deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to change the X coordinate in .burger-icon:before - `transform: translateX(20px)` - it changes the Y as well.

You mean when you specify *only* `transform: translateY(10px)`?

Well yeah of course it does.

You are changing the value of **one single** CSS property only here - and that property is `transform`.

If you do not specify explicit values for the different transform functions - then those take their default values.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think I get the question.

> When I try to change the X coordinate in .burger-icon:before - transform: translateX(20px) - it changes the Y as well.

And in your code you have:

```
.burger-icon:before {
    transform: translateX(20px) **translateY(10px)** rotate(-45deg);
}
```

What are you trying to say? That if you change that code for:

```
.burger-icon:before {
    transform: translateX(35px) translateY(10px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

the y coordinate does algo change? Because that would be weird. But if you are changing it to:

```
.burger-icon:before {
    transform: translateX(35px);
}
```

it is normal, as you eliminated the `translateY` transform, so it goes back to its default value (0).

---

*I am just guessing here:*

Maybe you are trying to change the value of transform via JavaScript like so:

```
element.style.transform = "translateX(35px)";
```

Well in that case, it is as if you set the transform property value to "translateX(35px)", so we have the same situation as the one explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is a few years old, but I was wanting to do something similar: Change the translation of X without the translation of Y changing.

Because if you set transform: translateY(10px); and then under another CSS rule set transform: translateX(35px); it will overwrite the translation of Y, and set it back to 0.

I came up with a trick to do this however using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).
What you can do is set the translation to be the value of two variables, and change the value of the variables as needed.

```
#popup {
    --x:-50%;
    --y:-50%;
    
    transform:translate(var(--x), var(--y));
}
#popup.top {
    --y:--100%;
}
#popup.bottom {
    --y:0;
}
#popup.left {
    --x:-100%;
}
#popup.right {
    --x:0;
}
```